# CRM 4.0 - Is there a way to know if a contact from a specific marketing list has respond to a campaign?

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

I am wondering how can I do the following about MS CRM 4.0:
I want to know for a campaign if a contact from a specific marketing list has not replied yet.

The field custom in the campaign response form is a partyfield. CRM doesn’t allow a PartyList field to be queried using a QueryExpression

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Katya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot retrieve activityparty records directly, but you can use them in LinkEntities:

```
private bool contactHasResponded(Guid idCampaign, Guid idContact)
{
    QueryExpression qryCampaignResponses = new QueryExpression("campaignresponse");
    qryCampaignResponses.ColumnSet = new AllColumns();

    qryCampaignResponses.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
    qryCampaignResponses.Criteria.AddCondition("regardingobjectid", ConditionOperator.Equal, idCampaign);

    LinkEntity leContact = new LinkEntity("campaignresponse", "activityparty", "activityid", "activityid", JoinOperator.Inner);
    leContact.LinkCriteria = new FilterExpression();
    leContact.LinkCriteria.AddCondition("partyid", ConditionOperator.Equal, idContact);

    qryCampaignResponses.LinkEntities.Add(leContact);

    List<gcCampaignresponse> lstCampaignResponses = gcCampaignresponse.RetrieveMultiple(m_svcCrm, qryCampaignResponses);

    return (lstCampaignResponses.Count > 0);
}
```

This will tell you whether there's a campaign response for a given campaign and contact. (I use entity classes generated by Stunnware Tools, so the RetrieveMultiple call looks a little different, but I think you get my point).

If you turn this QueryExpression/LinkEntity construct upside down, you can also get all contacts that have responded to a given campaign (you can also restrict that to contacts in a certain marketing list through a second LinkEntity).

The only thing that's not possible directly with a single query is the "negative" check you are looking for, so you'll have to take this result and do an "outer join" against your marketing list to get the contacts that have **not** responded.

Comment: Hey! I have another question related to the same one. I want to have the result somewhere right? Is it possible to create a custom view that displays the linked entities somewhere? For example to create a custom view under contacts, that is going to display the non replied campaigns. As I do have already a system view for the contact entity that displays the records that have responded to a campaign. Is it possible that I create a custom one, that displays my joined result? I hope this makes sense, I do appreciate any help! :)

Comment: Unfortunately not, because due to that negative link condition, you can't build this as a single FetchXML query. Pretty much anything that can be built with FetchXML can be shown in an IFrame (including as a SiteMap or form navigation item) using the fetchData.aspx trick (http://mscrm4ever.blogspot.com/2009/03/display-fetch-in-iframe-part-2.html), but in this case you'd have to build your own list aspx page.

Comment: I was trying though ;) I will try with my own custom page then. Thank you for the quick response!